# (relational) database performance for a date/time point/interval

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

So I am doing a project in Access SQL and it has come along nicely. I have learned a lot about Access and VBA and this site has been helpful in the process.

Now I am facing a problem which is performance and since I have little experience in this kind of SQL work I come here for some thoughts.

I have a ~20 table relational database for around 100 sections which represent parts of a route. The Access database is essentially a map on which I drew several routes (via lines) that can be coloured dynamically - the color is determined by the specific question and calculated out of the database.

Here is a picture which explains it better. You can not click on lines in access so the buttons are set to be identical in colour and width to the lines and are clickable for more information.
[image: a thing]

The user can chose a date and it will display the progress of the route according to the question asked. Up to now, these questions were always binary "yes, or no" (green or red).

I have found that because of the complexity of the queries I have to pretty much prepare a temporary database for each query at startup, otherwise it is not possible to scroll through dates smoothly.

So anyway here is my specific problem:

Each section of the route can be in different phases (think construction) at a certain date. From "phase 0" to "done"

A new line is to be implemented which represents phases of a project. There are around 8 possible phases for all sections, which can happen at different times and - here is the thing - in a different order for each section AND not all phases happen on all sections.

What I have in the database are only starting dates - not ending dates - for each phase. The order of the phases has pretty much be determined by the order of the starting date.
At least each phase can only happen once for each section, so there is that.
As you can see this is a shitty thing for this kind of performance centric program.

I am certain it will involve one or several temporary databases.
My ideas:

1. Aggregate all dates into one row of a new table. Since the number of phases is set, there are columns for each phase - if it is needed, when it starts and when it ends. A loop now needs to go through each and check if the user-date falls into which phase. So:
   "SectionID - phase1needed phase1start phase1end ....."
   Advantage:

   - One can confirm the data manually and display it in secondary forms well
   - It keeps the database small
     Disadvantage:
   - The actual loop needs to go through (At worst) all phases to find the correct one.
2. Calculate a new database which is just "IdSection - Date - Phase" and calculate a phase for each Section and EVERY Day in an interval.
   Advantage:

   - This keeps the runtime calculations to one query per section
   - Access should work with large amounts of data
     Disadvantage:
   - I can not manually check if what I did was correct for all sections
   - Will take long at startup, like really long
   - It will take a lot of entries in that db

Now I ask which you would prefer, or even if there is a different method?
I can not really change much about the points of data I have.

In short I have to display intervals of time of different phases and in the database I only have starting points of time, no complete order of the phases.

Thank you for your thoughts, any experiences in these sort of things will help

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. It's unique to see the usage of MS Access in this application.

Comment: Yeah I know, there are a ton of limitations when it comes to forms and reports in Access but it does work! It is actually for an internship and there aren't really any IT people here and Access is the only program we have that might produce such a thing (no ms studio or sql server or whatever). So I have to work with what I have. If it means drawing 500 line segments and buttons, so be it. Kinda need this ;)

Comment: With option 1, **"The actual loop needs to go through (At worst) all phases to find the correct one"**, how many potentially are we talking?

Comment: The second option seems to be the classic solution, but I cannot quite see "Will take long at startup, like really long" or "It will take a lot of entries in that db". Why will it take really long? How many is "a lot"? Which version or Access?

Comment: @Matt: We are talking about 10 phases, however it just came to me that one phase can be there multiple times (stops during construction). So essentially I have to find a different way to set up some sort of time table for each section. I would want to calculate this beforehand because my (much more trivial) calculations now are already taking too long to process. I guess my question for the first approach would be: how do the pro's save a time table in a database? Calculate start/end and query each time?

Comment: @Remou: I currently save the binary results of my (3) queries in a temporary database. This calculation already takes 15 minutes to complete. I fear that if I implement it date wise, I will need at least 500 days for 100 sections each for average of 5 phases which puts me 250000 entries to be calculated. I don't have to do it on startup but on edit and only for the affected section, but I don't have an edit mask set up and I fear for the consistency of my data if it is not calculated regurlarly. What if someone just dry-changes some dates? I hope this makes sense. Access is 2010.

Comment: "This calculation already takes 15 minutes to complete." seems quite a long time. You are sure you have optimized the queries? Any chance of running a complete update at night and using Data Macros on daytime updates?

Comment: No I now little about SQL optimization to be honest. Here is one example of such a query in pseudoSQL: "Select A Section WHERE For Prerequisite 1 - 1) NOT Exists a prerequisite that is marked incomplete 2) NOT Must exist a prerequisite entry but none exists OR 3) NOT the prerequisite is there but the date is larger than the user-date OR 4) no prerequisite is needed for this section.  ---- This solves all the cases which can happen. This is done for 5-6 prerequisites per section for around 100 sections. This takes a few seconds top IF there is a user-date (ie: At the map at runtime), but

Comment: [....] but to get the actual date where all prerequisites are complete (so for my temporal table) I have to search for the first occurence where this happens. That means I start at 1-1-2012 and go through each day. I think it may be smart to not look through all days but rather start at august and see if there are still prerequisites missing so then it can not be earlier than august - and then continue to always half the dates. This should be quicker, but I haven't implemented that yet. Still - those are a lot of calculations and they take a while.

Comment: [..] But doing that cuts down on the actual runtime where I do have the user selected date. Because then all I need to do is to query the section and do "where the switchdate is smaller than the userdate" and if it returns an entry the section gets greenlit. I would like to do this similarly for the timetable thing as I really want performance on my actual (runtime) map. But I don't quite know yet how to do this efficiently.

Comment: If you are using NOT Exists, you are missing all the speed you get from indexes. You would be much better off with a subquery / derived table and joins. Pseudo code does not work to explain a faster query. A properly designed query can be hundreds of times faster than a poorly designed query.

Comment: What Remou says is very true, e.g today I was given a query which took 6 minutes to run, one tiny change and it runs in 2 seconds. Are you able to update your question with a query you are currently using?  Also, depending on the data structure and how many times you need to re-iterate over a particular section, if possible to dump the data to an array then you may be able to build a VBA proc with greater performance.

Comment: I recently read the following on SQL ... it helped me a lot for this type of stuff. http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

Comment: @IMA - Congratulations, you've pretty much hit the limits of what Access can do. I would suggest using a real MS SQL server (even free SQL Express would be good) behind Access as it will give you much better query performance and a more full-featured query syntax. You can combine your prerequisites into larger single queries that will run faster, or schedule background jobs to pre-calculate data peridically if that's feasible. Here's a good link on how: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-access-to-sql-server-data-HA010341762.aspx#BM4

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for the late reply. I will try to implement different queries as suggested. Sadly, the decision of using an actual real database is out of my hands, as I can for example not gain Administrator rights and am forbidden from installing anything. I will try to make it work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you have a series of data similar to the form:

```
Section 1, Phase 7, Start Date = 11/07/2012
Section 1, Phase 2, Start Date = 12/14/2012
Section 1, Phase 3, Start Date = 12/28/2012
Section 2, Phase 1, Start Date = 11/04/2012
Section 2, Phase 9, Start Date = 12/30/2012
Section 3, Phase 4, Start Date = 11/19/2012
Section 3, Phase 5, Start Date = 12/06/2012
Section 3, Phase 3, Start Date = 12/11/2012
```

and you want to answer a question like "What phase is each section in on 12/15/2012?", is that correct?

The answer in this case should look something like the form:

```
Section 1, Phase 2
Section 2, Phase 1
Section 3, Phase 3
```

In order to do this, I'll assume you have a table called SECTION_PHASES with the following fields:

```
SECTION    Number
PHASE      Number
START_DATE Date/Time
```

What you need to do is figure out the maximum start date for each section that happened before your current input date, because that is the most recently active phase before the next phase change.  Once you do that, you can join that information back into your main table to determine what the phase was after that date.

You need to make one query SECTION_MAX_DATES that then has the following code in its SQL View:

```
SELECT [SECTION_PHASES].SECTION, Max([SECTION_PHASES].START_DATE) AS target_date
FROM SECTION_PHASES
WHERE [SECTION_PHASES].START_DATE<#12/15/2012#
GROUP BY [SECTION_PHASES].SECTION
ORDER BY [SECTION_PHASES].SECTION;
```

Once you have that query saved, you can join it as a subquery back to your original table.  Now, make another query SECTION_PHASE_AT_DATE which includes your original table and the previous query, then enter the following code in its SQL View:

```
SELECT SECTION_PHASES.SECTION, SECTION_PHASES.PHASE, SECTION_PHASES.START_DATE
FROM SECTION_MAX_DATES INNER JOIN SECTION_PHASES ON (SECTION_MAX_DATES.target_date=SECTION_PHASES.START_DATE) AND (SECTION_MAX_DATES.SECTION=SECTION_PHASES.SECTION)
ORDER BY SECTION_PHASES.SECTION;
```

That query will give you the result you are after, if I understand your question correctly.  There is no need to calculate the end dates if I understand you properly that a new start date for a given phase indicates the end of whatever phase was previously-current prior to the new date.

You'll still have a few edge cases to work out, like what happens if a section doesn't have a phase registered yet prior to the given date.  I'll also leave it to you to figure out how to parameterize the date in the WHERE clause of the 1st of the two queries, which is probably trivial for you given the progress you made already!  However, I think this is the SQL structure you were looking for to solve the data/calculation part of your problem.

Comment: Some clarification here: I take your problem to be that you want to draw another colored line and bar with 10 different colors for 10 different phases, and you need to know what phase each section is in for a given date. You and several others keep mentioning the end date of a phase, but you don't need that to solve this problem. I believe you want the end date because you are trying to determine the right phase with two predicates in a single query. However, that isn't necessary if you write the right query.

Comment: Thanks, I have essentially implemented this. I am happy to report that the project finished successfully and was a great success