# Recursively querying through structured table data / process design

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

After my first try to misappropriate Ms-Access - with your [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986215/relational-database-performance-for-a-date-time-point-interval) - turned out to be a great success, I have been sent back to do "more of this".

A bit of introduction you can skip if you want:

I am building a data foundation about certain projects from which I want to create analysises and overviews.

The data and findings are to be represented in programs like Excel or Powerpoint, so the process itself is very open. It will probably be very visual with detailed points on request.

However, the data might be changing periodically and if this turns out well, I might repeat the process.
Therefore I think the ideal way would be to have a data layer, then a fixed set of queries on that data and then I would (semi-)manually compile the results into a report in whatever format fits, maybe using external data analysis tools such as R in between.

Trouble is, the only database I have access to is.. well.. Ms Access 2010. I am not at liberty to install anything on this machine.
I could of course use non-install or online tools if you have recommendations for this.

tl;dr: I want to use Ms Access to query data from a relational db into tabular format to be processed further by hand, using as little of Ms-Access VBA and forms as possible.

---

I have since started to implement a prototype in ms-Access, a standard relational database.

One interesting problem I have come up with with this kind of design is that I have a table for companies involved in the projects. Along with this, I have a table of "relationship" - like stakeholding, ownerships or cooperations.
So let's say company A is building project A, but is just a subsidary of company B, which then partly owned by company C and so on.

Now let's say I want to query all companies involved in a project, but as owners I just want to show the last "elements" of the chain.
Imagine I want to sort the list by net assets, which is usually a figure which is only available for the public companies at the end of the chain, not the project subsidaries up the chain etc.

Is this possible with (Ms-)SQL or would I need to do this in VBA?
Right now I think I could manage do write a VBA function and dump it into a temporary table, but then I'd have to create forms and such.

Another idea that immediately springs from this is ´to answer the question "In which project does company C have stake" by a query. You can see where this is going.

I would prefer the database and the queries to be as flexible as possible (and in this case, independend from the actual Access).
So this time, no mock-program or user-interface. It was a pain to get what I want from Access in the last project and that was with a very specific question set...

But in general I am also open to use different tools if I can.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please ask only one question in your post.

Comment: I deleted the general question but left in the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modelling hierarchies in an RDBMS is a fairly tricky process - some (like Oracle) have built-in functionality to query hierarchical data, but I don't think Access does.

The best solution is to use a ["nested set" model.](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html) This allows you to model hierarchical data while using standard SQL; it's also pretty fast for querying.

If your data isn't hierarchical, the nested set isn't so useful; the typical solution in that case is to introduce a table to map the relationship - typically including the two related entities, and often with a "relationship type" field (e.g. "parent", "part owner" etc.). This is often called a Directed Acyclical Graph or DAG. There are several ways of modelling these in a database; a "Closure table" is probably the most efficient. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o) shows how to do this - it's a heavy read, but I think it answers your question.

Comment: So it seems I would be fine if I convert my relationship table into this format, so I will dive in and try to understand this (not a CS major here, obviously). But a quick related question before I do: My current setup allows me to characterize the relationship (type of stake, percentage of ownership etc). Is it possible to specifiy things like this in a nested-set model as well?

Comment: So my data does not have a root, in fact it can loop back onto itself. I don't think this algorithms works here, at least not in the sense of counterclockwise going around the tree. The immediate solution is to make one tree per project, but then the data is inconsistent. Am I missing something ?

Comment: There is an convert algorithm which I could use to do this on the fly, but I think several of those functions are not available in access-sql, which brings me back to vba.

Comment: Do you know an equivalent nested model which works more as a grid than a tree, ie. if elements are pairwise ordered but there exists no definite order for all elements?

Comment: I've updated the answer - if it's not strictly hierarchical, you can use a closure table.